# Are there sources that predict a process of redemption?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, messianic-redemption

I have been told that recent history reflects the **process** of redemption - גאולה. Whether or not this is true, I want to know if there are sources, in Tanakh or later, which predict such a process.

Comment: See the book of Daniel with Rashi. Rav Saadya Gaon in Emunos v'Deos lays out a long potential process. Ramchal in Da'as Tevunos says all history will ultimately be revealed to be leading up to the tikkun of world and final geulah.

Comment: @N.T. Any chance of a reference, especially to Da'as Tevunos please?

Comment: It's pretty much the main topic of the sefer.

Answer (score 3):

See [Sanhedrin 97a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.97a.2?lang=bi), specifically:

> ת"ר שבוע שבן דוד בא בו שנה ראשונה מתקיים מקרא זה והמטרתי על עיר אחת ועל עיר אחת לא אמטיר שניה חיצי רעב משתלחים שלישית רעב גדול ומתים אנשים ונשים וטף חסידים ואנשי מעשה ותורה משתכחת מלומדיה ברביעית שובע ואינו שובע בחמישית שובע גדול ואוכלין ושותין ושמחין ותורה חוזרת ללומדיה בששית קולות בשביעית מלחמות במוצאי שביעית בן דוד בא
>
> The Sages taught in a baraita: With regard to the seven-year period, i.e., the Sabbatical cycle, during which the Messiah, son of David, comes: During the first year, this verse will be fulfilled: “And I will cause it to rain upon one city and cause it not to rain upon another city” (Amos 4:7). During the second year of that period, arrows of famine will be shot, indicating that there will be famine only in certain places. During the third year there will be a great famine, and men, women, children, the pious, and men of action will die, and the Torah is forgotten by those who study it. During the fourth year there will be plenty but not great plenty. During the fifth year there will be great plenty and they will eat, and drink, and rejoice, and the Torah will return to those who study it. During the sixth year, heavenly voices will be heard. During the Sabbatical Year, wars, e.g., the war of Gog and Magog, will be waged involving the Jewish people. During the year after the conclusion of the Sabbatical Year, the son of David will come.

Comment: This is a source - is it the only one?